# Round-off error

Tags: performance-tuning, numerics, special-functions

Assuming $0<q<1$. I built these two functions

```
A[k_,q_]:=Sum[PDF[BinomialDistribution[i, q], k]*PDF[ZipfDistribution[n], i], {i, k, Infinity}]
```

and

```
B[k_,q_]:=Piecewise[{
{(1/Zeta[n + 1])*PolyLog[n + 1, 1 - q], k == 0},
{(1/(Zeta[n + 1]*k!))*(q/(1 - q))^k*Sum[CoefficientList[Product[x - j, {j, 1, k - 1}],x][[-i]]* PolyLog[n + i - k, 1 - q], {i, 1, k}], k > 0}}]
```

Functions A and B are mathematically equivalent for $k\geq1$. (Function B is faster than function A.)

When I compute $A[25,0.6]$ and $B[25,0.6]$ with $n=3$, I start to get a little difference between the results $(5.61124*10^{-7},5.61132*10^{-7})$. So, the question is, why is this difference? Does anyone know how to avoid this round-off problem?

Comment: Mor me: `B[25, 0.6]` give me: `11.09` not: `5.61124*10^-7` ?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk It looks like there are some characters missing in the definition, note the big empty spaces in e.g.  `n    1`.

Comment: It's normal for different forms of the same mathematical expression to give different numerical approximations, especially when including things like infinite sums. For your particular case, you can use exact numbers: `A[25, 6/10] == B[25, 6/10] // FullSimplify` and `N[A[25, 6/10], 20]`. In general, see the many questions on this site about increasing precision of the various Mathematica functions, such as `Sum`

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk I'm sorry, you are right. I just edited the post with the correction.

Comment: Exact solvers (like `Sum`) sometimes have difficulty with inexact input (e.g. `0.6` instead of `6/10`).  The number `5.61124*10^-7` is the result for `A[]` returned by `NSum`.  Possibly `Sum` failed and called `NSum` as a backup.

Answer (score 1):

This calculates the symbolic infinite sum `A[]` for a given integer `n` and caches the result.  The result is used to compute subsequent values of `A[k, q, n]`.

```
ClearAll[A, B];
A[k_, q_, n_Integer?Positive] := (
  DownValues[A] = Prepend[
    DownValues[A],
    HoldPattern[A[kk_, qq_, n]] :> Evaluate@
      Sum[
       PDF[BinomialDistribution[i, qq], kk]*
        PDF[ZipfDistribution[n], i],
       {i, kk, Infinity}]];
  A[k, q, n])

B[k_, q_, n_Integer?Positive] := 
  Piecewise[{{(1/Zeta[n + 1])*PolyLog[n + 1, 1 - q], 
     k == 0}, {(1/(Zeta[n + 1]*k!))*(q/(1 - q))^k*
      Sum[CoefficientList[Product[x - j, {j, 1, k - 1}], x][[-i]]*
        PolyLog[n + i - k, 1 - q], {i, 1, k}], k > 0}}];
```

Difference on floating-point input:

```
A[25, 0.6, 3] - B[25, 0.6, 3]
```

> ```
> (*  3.27923*10^-12  *)
> ```

The exact diffference is zero (it takes a few seconds to evaluate the `HypergeometricPFQ` that appear in `A[k, q, 3]` on exact input):

```
Simplify[A[25, 6/10, 3] - B[25, 6/10, 3]]
```

> ```
> (* 0  *)
> ```

```
N[A[25, 6/10, 3] - B[25, 6/10, 3], 20]
```

> N::meprec: Internal precision limit $MaxExtraPrecision = 50.` reached while evaluating....
>
> ```
> (*  0.*10^-66  *)
> ```